# Set a fixed numerical ration between alternative sorted numbers

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, numbers, sequence

So I am working on a large text file made up of rows and rows of numbers,
below is just an short excerpt to help with the question, but it could even be a series of random incrementing numbers with all sorts of numerical gaps between each row.

```
267
368
758
936
1248
1415
1739
1917
```

I am looking for a way to set a fixed numerical gap between every second pair of numbers starting on the 2nd and 3rd number. such as 100 whist maintaining the numerical difference within each pair but this difference could be any number.

Such that if the numerical gap was set to 100 the above example would become:

```
267
368
#      gap of 100
468
646
#      gap of 100
746
913
#      gap of 100
1013
1191
```

would anybody know of a possible one liner to do this in terminal of a shell script. Thanks

Comment: The input seems to be sorted, is that the case? What happens when the first three lines are `267` `368` `369`?

Comment: the third line of 369 would become 468, the idea being that the difference between each even number + the following number would become 100. and the difference between each odd number + the following number would be retained. also yes the input will be sorted as the numbers will be continually incrementing but at a rate of which could be considered random

Comment: I'm confused. is the output correct for the given input?

Comment: for this output I used a calculator and after adding 100 to the second number (368+100=468) 468 became the third number.I then added on the difference of the original 3rd and 4th number 936-758=178 to 468, 468+178 =646 and continued on this process to create the output, however this inst piratical for 1000's of lines of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit clumsy, but for starters this would do, I guess. It reads the list of numbers from `stdin` (i.e. start with `cat numbers.txt` or the like), then pipe it into the rest.

```sh
paste - - | {
        read -r x m;    echo $x;          echo $m
  while read -r x y; do echo $((m+=100)); echo $((m+=y-x)); done
}
```

```
267
368
468
646
746
913
1013
1191
```

Explanation: `paste - -` lets us read two numbers at once, so we can read line by line (two numbers). The first pair is printed out unchanged, but the subsequent pairs only serve as the base for calculating the diffrence, which is added onto a running variable, which also increments by `100` on each iteration.

---

Here's a rewrite as parametrized function, and without the use of `paste`:

```sh
addgaps() {
  read -r m; echo $m; read -r m; echo $m
  while read -r x; read -r y; do echo $((m+=$1)); echo $((m+=y-x)); done;
}
```

```sh
cat numbers.txt | addgaps 100
```

Comment: How do I save the parameterized function to my system, apology if its an overreach of a question, its just I have really struggled to find an easy to understand explanation of how to do it in the past so am often limited into looking for one line terminal solutions. which are often limiting

Comment: @missway It depends on your use case (and your system setup). As you're using `bash`, one way would be to put it in your `~/.bashrc` file so it gets sourced every time you open up a new bash shell. But if you're running your code from script files (rather than entering the commands on the command line in a terminal) then placing this into your according script files would suffice as well.

Comment: Thank you so much and also for taking the time to expand your answer into a more detailed explanation, really appreciate it